# Google App Engine Python -> configure yaml and websockets

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, websocket, yaml

I`m beginning programmist with google API working in python.
I have pycharm 3.4.1 version.

I 'm trying to make a project (backend) of game bomberman. It is like i have to use content of already written game in javascript. I have my project folder and there i have this content: ![link at the bottom][1]

1. I don't understand how exactly i should modify my yaml file to use content of web folder. I need handlers to java script, css and etc. using content of web. If someone could show me example of javascript import then I think I would be able to do analogically the same with others handlers.
2. What's more. I ve been searching information about implementation websockets in python using google API but I just cant find anything useful or I just don't understand the info. I would appreciate if somebody could show me how to implement websockets and add short explanation. Please be easygoing on me because it's my first approach to google API and i don't know much about it.

   Thanks for help and sorry for mistakes if I did any in the text:)

   [1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNJCz.png

Answer (score 1):

1 - To handle static files in your App Engine instance, you can add something similar to the following in your app.yaml file:

```
handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css

- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js
```

Just place your files in the static/css or static/js directories in your project.  This allows you to access the css and javascript files from the /css and /js paths on your site.  An example js import in your html file would be:

```
<script src=“/js/your-file.js"></script>
```

More options for configuring your static files is in the App Engine docs at:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig

2 - App Engine has the Channel Python API available.  You can find more info on that at;

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/

However, depending on your needs, some have indicated this is too slow for some situations.  You can also create a Compute Engine instance and run Node.js with socket.io for real-time communication between users.  This is a little more involved than the basic App Engine instance but you can see that environment layout in this real-time game example:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/